# Trying different input combinations for a tensorflow model

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have a neural network constructed in Tensorflow, and am using sentiment dimensions to try construct a predictive model. A few dimensions are Anger, Sad, Joy, Surprise, Positive, Negative, etc.. My aim is to try to combine different dimensions to see if I can find a non-linear relationship between them (I'm using a self-organizing fuzzy neural network) with what I am trying to predict. (e.g. 'Anger Surpise', 'Anger, Sad', 'Sad, Joy, Surprise', etc.)

**What I have tried:**
I have got all of the different combinations using the 'itertools' library. I then created a function that takes in the columns I would like to try, and then splits my pandas dataframe into training and testing, trains the model, and returns an output.

I have tried calling this function using .map on a pandas dataframe with one column consisting of the combinations, I've also tried using a threadpool, and also just a simple loop over the list of combinations and calling my function, however the time taken gets exponentially slower, and I think this is to do with the garbage collector not doing its job (my RAM usage also becomes very high). I then attempted to *del* all of the training, testing dataframes and model after every function call however it did not help.

tl;dr Is there a good way to try different combinations of inputs on a tensorflow model?

Answer (score 0):

Your problems seems complex - there is a lot of factors to determine.

Firstly - I suggest to construct data structure for that type of operation - and make some research in existing codebases on github.

For strictly operating with images & face recognition - **cv2** and **openCV**.
That type of model basically work on face recognitioin & positions of points in (x,y) and euclidean distance based on this.

In the process of declaring and adjustinig layer - it's possibility to mix those layers -
(Conv64, Pooling, Conv128, Conv258, Conv512)
eg.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

(Reference: https://github.com/atulapra/Emotion-detection/blob/master/src/emotions.py)

And to define the previius mentioned factors eg.

(0=Angry, 1=Disgust, 2=Fear, 3=Happy, 4=Sad, 5=Surprise, 6=Neutral)

So after categorizing emotions:

There is a need for reading position of points - point by point, something like:

```
for(x, y, w, h) in images
```